Is my switch a four-way?
I need to replace an old 15A switch. It has 2 white wires on the left and 2 red wires on the right, plus a ground wire at the bottom. Does this mean it is a 4 way switch?
I want to use a new Leviton 3-way switch decora edge series but I don't think it is the right one. Also the switch itself has plastic sides. Is it a special switch or is it just an old kind? It was installed in 2002-2003. Thank you!

Four ways have four screws/wires plus ground.  Four ways are used with two three ways to control one light or set of lights.

Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

it might be a two pole switch or a "4 way"

The easiest way to tell if an existing switch is 4-way: Are there at least 2 other switches that control the same light? Otherwise, if it is the only switch controlling a light, it is likely a two-pole switch (one that interrupts both the hot and neutral wires).

If the wires are in conduit, the whites are supposed to be neutrals only.  If so then that is a two-pole as in the other comment.  If the wires are in a cable, then whites can be used as hots/travellers as well as neutral which makes life more confusing.  If just red and white wires, then conduit makes sense, since it is rare for a cable to have only red and white(ground not counted).

If you add some photos of the switch box/switch and edit your question to confirm if there are other switches controlling the same light/s, then I would be happy to reopen the question.  Two pole switches are not as common as four ways, so we might have jumped to the wrong assumption.
